# I am automating web scraping using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, screen-scraping

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASnrs.png)]
this is my code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Edge(r"C:\Users\siddhi.tharval\Downloads\edgedriver_win64 (1).exe")
driver.get('https://www.makemytrip.com/flights/')
driver.maximize_window()
#to choose round trip
round_trip = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="top-banner"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]')
round_trip.click()
time.sleep(4)
#From city
fromcity = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'fromCity'))).click()
#from city input box
fromfield=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='From']")
fromfield.send_keys(dep_city)
#dropdown first suggestion
firstsuggestion= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-autowhatever-1-section-0-item-0"]')
firstsuggestion.click()
#tocity
tocity= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'toCity'))).click()
#tocity input box
tofield= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='To']")
tofield.send_keys(des_city)
#dropdown first suggestion 
sugges=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-autowhatever-1-section-0-item-0"]').click()
time.sleep(10)
#start date
startdate = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='DayPicker-Day'][2]").click()
time.sleep(10)
#end date
enddate = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='DayPicker-Day'][3]").click()
#From 
search= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@class,"widgetSearchBtn")]'))).click()
```

please give me solution to get flights page on my webdriver instead of this network error. after clicking on search button in webdriver website it is not opening flights list page showing nework problem as i shared image of error.

Comment: How are we supposed to solve a network problem with the site? Are you able to execute these steps successfully manually?